# Consulta preparada en java con cláusula LIKE con comodines (%

Tags: java, sql

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta preparada en java con una cláusula SQL del estilo a

```
String sql = "SELECT xxx FROM xxxx WHERE UPPER(?) LIKE ?";

PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, "%cod%");
ps.setString(1, "'%cod%'"); // otra forma
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

He hecho varias pruebas con los mensajes de respuestas que he visto por aqui, pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar, en cuando meto algo en el campo de búsqueda que sustituye el texto 'cod' con el contenido del campo. Pero en cuanto introduzco algo y le doy a buscar no sale ningún resultado.

Comment: Aparte de que estás usando `ps.setString(1,`  para ambos parámetros, hay un problema más de fondo. No parece tener mucho sentido tu query porque no usa valores de la tabla sino literales.( Podrías darnos un ejemplo del query final que esperas?).

Answer (score 1):

Tu query recibe 2 parametros, pero solo estas pasando uno

```
String sql = "SELECT xxx FROM xxxx WHERE UPPER(?) LIKE ?";
                                               1       2
```

Comment: Me he confundido y sobra el primer ?, gracias y disculpa.

Comment: Si tu query queda asi SELECT xxx FROM xxxx WHERE UPPER(xxxx) LIKE ?, si tu parámetro tiene minúsculas NUNCA encontrará ningún registro.

Comment: String sql = "SELECT * FROM animal a WHERE a.deleted=0 AND UPPER(a.code) LIKE ?"; //... ps.setString (1,"'%"+campo.toUpperCase()+"%'");

Comment: Quita las comillas simples del parametro.

Comment: ps.setString (1,"%"+campo.toUpperCase()+"%"); -> Así también lo he probado y nada de nada.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner los datos de tu tabla?

Comment: codigo-nombre-propietario-...
cod_animal1-animal1-prop1
cod_animal2-animal2-prop2


 
ps.setString (1,"%"+a.code.toUpperCase()+"%")
Introduzco en el campo de búsqueda "cod" (sin comillas) y no saca ningún resultado. Si no pongo nada, como eso lo compruebo, funciona, porque no rellena, ni usa el LIKE, ni la consulta con parámetros.

Comment: Tecnicamente el SELECT * FROM animal a WHERE UPPER(a.code) LIKE '%COD%' deberia devolverte registros. Prueba esta query directamente sobre la BBDD

Comment: Es un programa que estoy modificando que no he hecho yo, y que estaba sin consultas preparadas y estoy corrigiendo lo del SQL inyection y antes funcionaba perfectamente y si quito la consulta preparada, funciona correctamente.

Comment: Lo unico que se me ocurre es que **a.code.toUpperCase()** tenga un valor extraño.

Answer (score 0):

Será porque no envías el cod como texto en el string...

```
String sql = "SELECT xxx FROM xxxx WHERE UPPER(?) LIKE '?'";

PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, "cod");
ps.setString(2, "%cod%");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Revisa también lo que mencionó Lithorell, si no hay registros con mayúsculas, no retornará resultados.

Answer (score 0):

```
            + "WHERE (nombre LIKE ? "
            + "OR cedula LIKE ? "
            + "OR telefono LIKE ?) "
            + "AND idEstado = 1 "
            + "ORDER BY idPersona";
    try {
        st = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1, "%" + criterio + "%");
        st.setString(2, "%" + criterio + "%");
        st.setString(3, "%" + criterio + "%");
```

Comment: Explica brevemente cómo funciona este código: lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score -2):

No es posible ocupar un PreparedStatement para definir el campo a comparar como lo quieres hacer aquí

`WHERE UPPER(?)`

En todo caso deberías concatenar el valor a tu query

`String sql = "SELECT xxx FROM xxxx WHERE UPPER( " + "%cod%" + ") LIKE ?";`

Si el tema que te preocupa es el SQL Inyection deberías ocupar una metadata en otra tabla para poder obtener el campo que quieres modificar pero es otro tema muy diferente a lo que quieres hacer con el PreparedStatement.